# Safe Multi-threaded Counters Management in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I have a scenario where I want to monitor performance of different modules with simple counters. The code is written in clojure. There is an unknown number of possible counters I will need to monitor during running, and once in a while I report them (to statsd).

Here is my code:

```
     (defn counter-incrementer []
      (let [counters (atom {})
            atom-increment (fn [counters-unwrapped metric-name metric-value]
                             (assoc counters-unwrapped metric-name (+ (get counters-unwrapped metric-name 0) metric-value)))
            increment (fn [metric-name metric-value]
                (swap! counters atom-increment metric-name metric-value))]
        (fn [metric-name metric-value]
          (increment metric-name metric-value))))
```

Then in each place in a code I want to update the counter, I will use:

```
      (def inc-fn (counter-incrementer))
       .
       .
       .
      (inc-fn "number of logged users" 10)
```

This code works, but I feel it's not the best solution to the problem. For example, each time I want to update one counter, I lock all the counters map.

Is there a best-practice solution for this kind of problem in clojure?

Comment: Consider using `update` or `update-in` instead of `assoc` (http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  Also, you could use a separate atom (holding an integer) for each counter: `(def num-logged-users (atom 0))`

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how many counters I will need in advance, so i can't define one atom per each counter from the beginning, it must be created dynamically. (Example, if i would like to count users separately for each different country).
I can think about two solutions: 
Map of atom counters - but it seems difficult to synchronize the creation of each counter.
Factory of functions - each function holds an atom. But i have no idea if it's possible to do it in clojure

Comment: This post talks about different options in Java for high performance https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/JTN5yRgUl_I

Comment: Be aware that most mechanical-sympathy needs are way above 'normal' java (even Enterprise) use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep multiple metrics in one reference type and use only clojure, you can do so by using an agent map. Updates to agents are queued and handled by the agent thread pool, so there is no locking for the calling thread.

```
(def metrics (agent {:counter1 0,:counter2 0}))
(send metrics update-in [:counter1] inc)
@metrics
=> {:counter1 1, :counter2 0}
```

This way you can create new key value pairs dynamically when needed. `update-in` will create new keys when they're not in the map, but you will need to adjust your update function to account for nil values. This can be most practically done by compositing your original function with `fnil` and a default value.

```
(send metrics update-in [:counter3] (fnil inc 0))
@metrics
=> {:counter1 1, :counter3 1, :counter2 0}
(send metrics update-in [:counter3] (fnil inc 0))
@metrics
=> {:counter1 1, :counter3 2, :counter2 0}
```

You need to keep into account that updates aren't applied directly though. If there's still actions queued on the agent pool, it will prevent closing down the JVM process, unless a `(shutdown-agents)` is given.

Comment: So a question. In a case of 3 threads concurrently trying to update the agent map's counter1, does it maintain the order of the updates? i.e (+5 -> +5 -> -10), if at some point i try to deref the value can i get accidently -10? And another question, both for agents and atoms: the suggested update-in and assoc still can't be used to create new counters atomically, because i first need to check if the counter already exist in the map before i can decide if use update-in or assoc, though the solution in my code with 'code'[atom-increment], still looks like the only one.. or am i wrong?

Comment: There's no need for assoc, update-in is all you need, see edited example

Comment: The official agent documentation is a bit hazy about update order from different threads. I did some experiments with `add-watch` and delayed updates, and it seems updates on the same agent are done in the order they are queued in. Perhaps it's a good new question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, optimal solution to have one atom per counter.

Though, the best solution is to take production ready metrics library, like https://github.com/sjl/metrics-clojure

Here is usage for counters:
http://metrics-clojure.readthedocs.org/en/latest/metrics/counters.html